# Finite dimensional rational representaton is independent of choice of basis

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $(\rho,V)$ be an $m$-dimensional representation of a group $G$. Then $V$ is said to be a rational representation of $G$ if, after choosing a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$, we have $[\rho_{ij}(g)]_\mathcal{B}$ is a regular function on $G$. Hopefully, if we select another basis, $\mathcal{B}'$ of $V$, one would hope that the representation $[\rho_{ij}(g)]_{\mathcal{B}'}$ also consists of regular functions.

But everywhere I've found a definition of this, they just assert this is the case and never prove it. I'm presuming you can work with the transition matrix from $\mathcal{B}$ to $\mathcal{B}'$ but I don't see it right away.

Comment: What does "regular" mean here?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Sorry, I should have said that $G$ is a linear algebraic group, so each $\rho_{ij}$ should be a morphism of varieties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $G$ is an algebraic group (or possibly a Lie group). If $M$ is the change of bases matrix, then
$$
\rho(g)_{\mathcal{B}'}=M\rho(g)_\mathcal{B}M^{-1}.
$$
Because $M$ is a constant matrix (entries won't depend on $g$), this means that the matrix entries $[\rho_{ij}(g)]_{\mathcal{B}'}$ are just scalar linear combinations of
the matrix entries $[\rho_{ij}(g)]_\mathcal{B}$. The latter were given to be regular functions of $g$ (rational if $G$ is algebraic, differentiable in the case of Lie groups), so the same applies to former.